# How to change strength of studio light via python? (UPBGE)

Tags: python, shaders, game-engine, lighting, shader-nodes

Hello I would like to have the studio light strength change from 1 to 0 when entering a new scene. I assume that this is achievable via python, but what would the required script be? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code here:

```
import bpy

space = None
for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
        
        for s in a.spaces:
            s.shading.studiolight_intensity = 0.15203
```

just as a hint how you can "see" what the command is: open the console, change the strength and you see the command in the console ;)

[image]

Comment: Hello, when I connect this script to a keyboard sensor (e.g. press G to activate) and press P to run the game, when I press G it has no effect real-time, but shows the effect after pressing Esc and returning to the viewport. Is there a method for this working real-time? Thanks.

Comment: i think in game you would have to change the background color.....this is "just" viewport shading, not rendered result

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome!!